# disabling the list link on a wiki page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a wikipage within a website.A list has been added to this page.But apart from adding a new item to list whenever title link for this list is clicked it takes user directly to the main list where the user can view all items that were previously added by all employees.how can the list name on wikipage can be disabled so that by clicking on it user stays on the same page and is not redirected towards the original list and its content.
[image]

have a look at the image above.I am using sharepoint foundation 2013
can this be done using any out of the box feature or by using coding?

Comment: Just Remove the permission for that user

Comment: what kind of permission should be denied to achieve this?

Comment: i want the user to enter data but not allow him to go to the actual list page

Comment: Under page menu click on permission and check the checkbox near the user who do not want to view the list and then give k

Answer (score 0):

Add a script editor webpart with

```
<style>
  .ms-webpart-titleText { 
    display: none; 
  }
</style>"
```

Click **edit web part** of the script editor and under Layout check hidden.